# TeX Live won't work with custom class. Says Undefined control sequence \if@cref@hyperrefloaded

Tags: errors, texlive, document-classes, documentclass

since switching to Linux and therefore switching from MiKTeX to TeX Live, I'm having problems getting all my documents compiled with a custom class made by a fellow student from my university.

The class I'm using is the [iodhbwm](https://github.com/faltfe/iodhbwm), which is also available at CTAN. The class itself is based on `scrreprt`.

I prepared a minimal example, which works just fine in Overleaf, but not with my local compiler:

```
\documentclass[load-dhbw-templates]{iodhbwm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\dhbwsetup{%
    author              = John Doe
}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    % Print ToC
    \chapter{Test Chapter}\label{chap:test-chap}
\end{document}
```

Here is the [Error log](https://pastebin.com/bcgZPsGm)

I've already searched for possible solutions, but most are based on wrong usage of packages. I'm 100% confident, my minimal example is working with MiKTeX and in Overleaf.

If needed, I'm on Manjaro Linux with KDE Plasma, using TeXStudio 3.0.4 and TeX Live 2020.
Here are my [installed packages](https://pastebin.com/2q1U7ZfP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

`iodhbwm 2021-02-15 v1.2.2` fixes the issue.

### Original answer

The `iodhbwm` class uses a deprecated option to `\AfterPackage`. More precisely, it does

```
\AfterPackage!{hyperref}{<code to load cleveref>}
```

The current version of `scrlfile` no longer accepts `!` and this causes `cleveref` to be loaded before `hyperref`. Indeed, one of the first error messages you get is

```
! Package cleveref Error: cleveref must be loaded after hyperref!
```

Workaround until the class is updated: pass the `withdeprecated` option to `scrlfile`.

```
\documentclass[load-dhbw-templates,withdeprecated]{iodhbwm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\dhbwsetup{%
    author              = John Doe
}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    % Print ToC
    \chapter{Test Chapter}\label{chap:test-chap}
\end{document}
```

The fix to the class is easy: remove the `!` after `\AfterPackage`.

Comment: You literally saved my bachelor thesis! Thank you so much for this simple solution!